# getting "Cannot read property 'thumbnail' of undefined" in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

When i am trying to render name in html file is it showing properly but when i am trying to get category_image.thubmail in html, getting **Cannot read property 'thumbnail' of undefined** error
Details are given below

Json data

```
[
{
    "id": 22,
    "name": "Test Name",
    "slug": "test-name-english-news",
    "cataegory_image": {
        "thumbnail": "thumb Image",
        "medium": "medium image"
    }
}
]
```

category model file

```
    export interface ICategory {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  slug: string;
  category_image: {
    thumbnail: string;
    medium: string;
  };
}
```

HTML code

```
  <li *ngFor="let category of categories | async">
    {{category.name}}{{category.category_image.thumbnail}}
    <!-- <a href="#">test<img src="{{category.category_image.thumbnail}}" width="40" alt="{{category.name}}" /></a> -->
  </li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

property name in your JSON is different than what you have on your html.

category.**category_image**.thumbnail

"**cataegory_image**": {
        "thumbnail": "thumb Image",
        "medium": "medium image"
    }

there is an extra a after t in your JSON.